# UPDATE with Subqueries (WHERE/FROM)

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am attempting update a Yes/No field (Sealed) in a table called [Assets] from a subquery.

The subquery results contain the ID from [Assets] and the desired result of the field to be updated.

I have tried a few options, including WHERE or FROM clauses, but can't achieve the appropriate result.

Below is the basic Update statement and the subquery. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
UPDATE [Assets] SET Sealed = IsSealed

SELECT y.Asset AS Asset, 
       IIF(y.TotalSeals>0,Yes,No) AS IsSealed
FROM (
SELECT x.Asset, 
       SUM(IIF(x.BOMTypes="Seal",1,0)) AS BOMSeals, 
       SUM(IIF(x.MatMovTypes="Seal",1,0)) AS MMSeals, 
       SUM(IIF(x.POTypes="Seal",1,0)) AS POSeals, 
       (BOMSeals + MMSeals + POSeals) AS TotalSeals 
FROM (
SELECT [Data - Assets].ID AS Asset, 
       [Data - Inventory].Type AS BOMTypes, 
       NULL AS MatMovTypes, NULL AS POTypes, NULL AS TotalSeals 
FROM [Data - Inventory] INNER JOIN ([Data - Assets] INNER JOIN [Data - BOM] 
ON [Data - Assets].ID = [Data - BOM].Asset) 
ON [Data - Inventory].ID = [Data - BOM].Component 

UNION ALL 
SELECT [Data - Assets].ID AS Asset, NULL AS BOMTypes, 
       [Data - Inventory].Type AS MatMovTypes, 
       NULL AS POTypes, NULL AS TotalSeals 
FROM ([Data - Assets] INNER JOIN [Data - WO] 
ON [Data - Assets].ID = [Data - WO].Asset) 
INNER JOIN ([Data - Inventory] INNER JOIN [Data - MatMov] 
ON [Data - Inventory].ID = [Data - MatMov].Component) 
ON [Data - WO].ID = [Data - MatMov].WorkOrder 

UNION ALL 
SELECT [Data - Assets].ID AS Asset, 
       NULL AS BOMTypes, NULL AS MatMovTypes, 
       [Data - Inventory].Type  AS POTypes, NULL AS TotalSeals 
FROM ([Data - Assets] INNER JOIN [Data - WO] 
ON [Data - Assets].ID = [Data - WO].Asset) 
INNER JOIN ([Data - Inventory] INNER JOIN [Data - PO] 
ON [Data - Inventory].ID = [Data - PO].Component) 
ON [Data - WO].ID = [Data - PO].WorkOrder  
)  AS x 
GROUP BY x.Asset
)  AS y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table `Assets` contains a field `Asset` which corresponds to the `y.Asset` column in your subquery, then I would suggest the following:

```
update assets a inner join
(
    select y.asset, iif(y.totalseals > 0, Yes, No) as issealed
    from 
    (
       ***TLDR
    ) y
) t on a.asset = t.asset 
set a.sealed = t.issealed
```

This assumes that your subquery does not contain any form of aggregation, else the query will not be updateable.

If your subquery includes aggregation, you could use a domain aggregate function, such as `DCount` or `DSum` (depending on the operations performed by your subquery).

Comment: Ah, my subquery does in fact include aggregation. Can you explain why aggregations are not updateable?

Comment: @AdamB Because there is no longer a one-to-one relationship between records and the JET database engine has such a limitation. I have updated my answer above with an alternative suggestion.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the full code, including aggregates. Can you further explain how to implement domain aggregates to achieve the desired result? Forgive me, I'm very new to SQL.